# Merging multiple files based on column using a for loop in Unix

Tags: unix

I am trying to merge about 500 files into one, as follow,

Each file has 2 columns, for example:

File 1: filename is N1

```
X1  1.1

X2  2.1

X3  1.2
```

File 2: filename is N2

```
X1  1.8

X2  1.6

X3  2.2
```

.
.
.

I would like the final output to be like this:

```
    N1   N2   ...   N500

X1  1.1  1.8  ...   ...

X2  2.1  1.6  ...   ...

X3  1.2  2.2  ...   ...
```

How do I use a for loop to do this with the file names becoming the column names in the new output file? Or without a for loop maybe? Thanks.

Comment: You get 90% of the way with `paste N*`

Comment: Try `man join`.

Comment: Yeah but I need the file names to be the column names.

Comment: Must the format be precise (each column right-justified)? And does every file have the same X's in the same order?

Comment: The Xs and X order are the same in each file, so sorting is not necessary here.